# Visual Studio 2017 won't let me create c++ specialized template

Tags: c++

```
template<> 
class A<char> { // Error here
public:
    A(char c)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
};
```

When I hover on A, it says "A is not a template".

Comment: And where is the templated `A`?

Comment: A is not a template, why do you think it is?

Comment: i dont get the close reasons. How is this "too broad" ??

Comment: Probably because you never declared a class template called "A". You can't specialise something that does not exist.

Comment: I watched a tutorial, and tried to do exactly same thing. It doesn't work on mine.

Comment: I got it. Thanks guys.

Comment: i am not going to tell you how you should learn, but be careful with online c++ tutorials, there are just too many of poor quality (once you can identify the good ones you probably dont need them anymore ;). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for books

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the template before you can specialize it:

```
// declare the template
template <typename T>   // no need to define it
struct A;               // if you only want the specialization

// declare and define the specialization
template<> 
struct A<char> {};
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you.